# Attempt of proving "Compactness theorem" in Mendelson Logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson - page 93, exercise 2.54.The question is something like this:

> Compactness. If all finite subsets of the set of axioms of a  theory $K$ have models, prove that $K$ has a  model.

My attempt:

Lets say all finite subsets of the set of axioms of a  theory $K$ have models but $K$ doesn't have a  model.If $K$ does not have a model , then that means $K$ is inconsistent (Because , if $K$ was consistent , then it would have a denumerable model).So for any wf $\mathscr B$ , $\vdash_K \mathscr B$ and $\vdash_K \lnot \mathscr B$. There is only a finite set of axioms used in the proof of $\vdash_K \mathscr B$ and $\vdash_K \lnot \mathscr B$. Let $S$ be a theory comsisting of only the axioms that are used in the proof of $\vdash_K \mathscr B$ and $\vdash_K \lnot \mathscr B$ and all of the logical axioms.Clearly $S$ is a subtheory of $K$ and $\vdash_S \mathscr B$ and $\vdash_S \lnot \mathscr B$.So , $S$ is inconsistent.

This is how far I was able to get to.Can someone give me a hint about what to do next?

Comment: You are very nearly done: you have identified a finite subset of the axioms of $K$ that are inconsistent and hence cannot have a model, contradicting the assertion that any finite subset of the axioms of $K$ has a model.

Comment: @RobArthan "You are very nearly done: you have identified a finite subset of the axioms of $K$ that are inconsistent and hence cannot have a model" is there a proof for this?

Comment: I don't have the same edition of Mendelson as you. But if not too much has changed, (the contrapositive of) this fact is stated in the proof of the Skolem-Löwenheim theorem with a reference to an earlier discussion of interpretations.

Comment: **$1$**.Original: If K is inconsistent , then K does not have a model. 
**$2$**.Contrapositive (of $1$): If K has a model , then K is consistent.
**$3$**.Skolem-Löwenheim: If K has a model , then K has a denumerable model.
**$4$**.Prop 2.17: Every consistent theory K has a  denumerable model.

I cant seem to find a way to use no $3$ and $4$ to prove $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Oh wait , nevermind. I found the line you were refering to "If $K$ has a model, then $K$ is consistent, since no wf can be both true and false for the same model $M$" .My bad.